# UILocalNotification is not firing on correct time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I am trying to set a `UILocalNotification` but it is not firing on time. It fires 2 hours later then it should. Here how I calculate the alert date:

```
NSDate *etkinlikDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents: components];
sourceTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
destinationTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];

sourceGMTOffset = [sourceTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:etkinlikDate];
destinationGMTOffset = [destinationTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:etkinlikDate];
interval = destinationGMTOffset - sourceGMTOffset;

etkinlikDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:interval sinceDate:etkinlikDate];
```

here `etkinlikDate` returns me the correct value. (The date I want to fire the notification)

and here how I set the alert:

```
UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
localNotification.fireDate = etkinlikDate;
localNotification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %@", [sClass className], etkinlikSaati];
localNotification.soundName = @"receivedmessage.caf";
localNotification.alertAction = @"Show me the item %d";
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];

// Request to reload table view data
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadData" object:self];
```

Although the etkinlikDate is correctly set the local notification is not firing on time.

---

Update: Lets say I want to set the alert on 16:30.

etkinlikDate returns 16:30 but alert fires on 18:30.

Comment: It looks like you're doing more work than you need to. You shouldn't need to wrangle the GMT offset by hand, for example. What do you mean by 'etkinlinkDate is correctly set' ? Can you give example values, and when you expect the notification to fire?

Comment: I think that GMT is necessary to set correct time. Otherwise it returns me 2 hours later that it should return. Added some example values as well.

Comment: Did you try using the original `etkinlikDate` value, the one before you attempted the timezone adjustment? You are probably just confused by the output of logging the date.

Comment: Re the example data - when you say 'etkinlikDate returns 16:30', what time zone is that? I'm guessing it's in GMT. So you've set the timer for 16:30 GMT and it's firing at 18:30 local time (which is 16:30 GMT).